# Frame numbering ( a part from certain pages)

Tags: beamer

I work in a beamer presentation and I have no idea how I can add the frame numbering to all but certain slides. My code is as follows (MWE):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
% Volba vzhledu prezentace.
%
% Pro další možnosti, barevná schémata a použité fonty, navštivte:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % nebo zkuste Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,...
  \usecolortheme{default} % nebo zkuste albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % nebo zkuste serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] % to number

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{page number appendix}
{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{At the Intersection between Machine Learning and Econometrics: Theory and Applications}
\author{\underline{Nutarelli Federico}}
\institute{IMT School for Advanced Studies Lucca}
\date{}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo_eng.png}
}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]{Overview}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\include{intros}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Econometrics and Machine Learning}
\begin{itemize}%[leftmargin=1em]
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Rightarrow$}
    \item The statistics community has largely accepted the Machine Learning (ML) revolution (e.g., Athey and Imbens, 2019) 
    \pause \item \textit{If authors
see econometrics as "decision making under uncertainty", their toolbox cannot ignore
the fundamentals of machine learning.} (Chamberlain, 2000)
 \pause \item The non-parametric nature of machine learning
helps uncover hidden relationships between the predictors
and the outcome variable that traditional econometric approaches could overlook.
\pause \item Data analysis in statistics and econometrics can be divided into four parts: prediction, summarization, estimation, and hypothesis testing. Machine learning can help with the first one without the restrictions of model-based statistical methods (Breiman, 2001).
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

EDIT: I found this solution to be applied at the end of the above code without "\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]":

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{ \hspace{1em}    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber }
```

but the problem now lies whenever I want to hide the page number for some slide. For instance with the nonumbering option I get this, where you can notice the page number appearing at the bottom right (the counter is 0, but still I would like to hide it completely):

[image]

The code for the above is simply this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]{Overview}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Thank you,

Federico